# Trigger entity validation programmatically

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

Question is simple.

I have an Entity with validation contraints.

I also have a service which is going to create such entities.

Problem is, it does not trigger validations like `@Assert\Expression`. See below.

This is a huge bummer. How can I trigger such validation programmatically please ?

I need to automatically validate a `Booking` instance against all the constraints defined in the `Booking` class definition.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BookingRepository")
 */
class Booking
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Slot", inversedBy="bookings")
     * @Groups({"booking"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Expression(
     *     "value == null or (value.getStatus() == constant('App\\Entity\\Slot::STATUS_ACTIVE'))",
     *     message="Vous ne pouvez pas réserver cette date."
     * )
     */
    private $slotId;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `validator` service from Symfony ([documentation about the Validator component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator.html)).

Call the `validate` method on your newly created entity in your service.

Comment: Thanks that's a good start, but I'd like it to validate a `Booking` instance with the constraints defined on the entitie's class definition (comments). I'll update my question.

Comment: Please also read: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html. This is the case by default.

Comment: Ok I just needed to use an injected `$validator` instance so it's aware of Doctrine registry. So `function(ValidatorInterface $validator) { $validator->validate(new Booking()); }`